# Node, Angular Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have been following the [a scotch.io](https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-a-single-page-todo-app-with-node-and-angular) tutorial to create my first node and angular app. I have seen that relative paths are a common issue online for the `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory` which as far as I can tell is the same as the tutorial so I'm why its not working.

The full error message is: 
`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat'/Users/badman/githubRepos/travelGuide/app/public/index.html'
at Error (native)`

[My folder structure is here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlaBc.png)
My server.js:

```
// set up web server
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

// routes
require('./app/routes.js')(app);

// listen (start app with node server.js)
app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("server going");
})
```

routes.js:

```
module.exports = function (app) {

  app.get('*', function (req, res) {
      res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html'); // load the single view file (angular will handle the page changes on the front-end)
  });

};
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Your `public` folder isn't inside the `app` folder in the picture you've posted, so clearly `app/public/...` is wrong ?

Comment: Yeah that's clearly the issue, showing my inexperience here! Which part of the route is adding the "app" part? It's the same as scotch.io but obviously my request is going to a different directory. Isn't app.get just calling express to make the route, rather than adding it to the path?

Comment: Did you setup app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));  so express can serve your static files from the public folder.You can also try out instead import   path = require('path'); and then use  app.use('/', express.static(path.resolve('./public')));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and I moved

```
  app.get('*', function (req, res) {
      res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html'); // load the single view file (angular will handle the page changes on the front-end)
  });
```

to **server.js** right under the `require('./app/routes.js')(app);` and that fixed it! Because it was looking for **index.html** in the wrong place when a server-side route was being called. I think you could have also changed the path too but I found this to be clearer.